# Map keeps returning null values

Tags: flutter

I have an issue with creating `POST` request. No matter what I input, I keep getting null as email and password.

```dart
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  late LoginRequestModel requestModel;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    requestModel = LoginRequestModel();
  }
```

I have two TextFormFields where I added
`onSaved: (input) => requestModel.email = input`

Then whenever when input values and I submit on my button it keeps printing `{email: null, password: null }`

```dart
print(requestModel.email); //null
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class LoginRequestModel {
   String? email;
   String? password;

  LoginRequestModel({ this.email, this.password} );

  factory LoginRequestModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      return LoginRequestModel(
        email: json['email'],
        password: json['password']
    );
    }
}
```

```dart
class Auth {
  static String baseUrl = "MY_API";

  var client = http.Client();

  void login(LoginRequestModel model) async {
     await client.post(Uri.parse(baseUrl), body: model);
  }

}
```

```dart
TextFormField(
                cursorColor: Colors.black,
                obscureText: false,
                onSaved: (input) => requestModel.email = input,
```

How do I successfully make a POST request?

Comment: Can you share the as well where you are assigning values?

Comment: @Diwyansh I've edited post

Comment: why you don't use the textediting controller?

Comment: @JahidulIslam, I've added `Future<LoginRequestModel>? _requestModel;` and added to TextFormField `controller: _controller,`. But I need to use on another TextFormField as well.

Comment: `TextEditingController` only works for one text field for me..

Comment: @squnk please check out my answer, i hope it will work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you can do with the `TextEditingController` for responsive input and for post network call you need to `jsonEncode`

```
class ResponsiveInput extends StatelessWidget {
  ResponsiveInput({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  TextEditingController emailTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordTextEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: emailTextEditingController,
            cursorColor: Colors.black,
            obscureText: false,
            onSaved: (input) {},
          ),

          TextFormField(
            controller: passwordTextEditingController,
            cursorColor: Colors.black,
            obscureText: false,
            onSaved: (input) {},
          ),

          TextButton(onPressed: (){
            LoginRequestModel login = LoginRequestModel(
              email: emailTextEditingController.text,
              password: passwordTextEditingController.text,

            );

            Auth().login(login);

          }, child: Text("Login"))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For complete source code: [link](https://gist.github.com/Jahidul007/c49b79830d21512768f3a8d79ca35887)

output:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that there's some problem while `saving` your Form Try below code

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  LoginRequestModel _requestModel = LoginRequestModel();
  GlobalKey<FormState> _globalKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      body: Form(
        key: _globalKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              cursorColor: Colors.black,
              obscureText: false,
              onSaved: (input) => _requestModel.email = input,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              cursorColor: Colors.black,
              obscureText: false,
              onSaved: (input) => _requestModel.email = input,
            ),
            Divider(),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_globalKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    _globalKey.currentState!.save();
                    Auth().login(_requestModel);
                  }
                },
                child: Text("Submit"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```